# TikZ block diagram with multiple arrows not from centre of block

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a rather simple diagram but I don't know how to get the multiple arrows on the left not leaving the centre of the node.

[image: The block diagram I would like to create]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two options; using anchors and some shifts, and using the `<name>.<angle >` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum size=2cm] (x) {X};
\draw[->] ([yshift=-10pt]x.west) -- node[fill=white] {a} +(-1cm,0pt);
\draw[->] ([yshift=10pt]x.west) -- node[fill=white] {b} +(-1cm,0pt);
\draw[->] (x.120) -- node[fill=white] {c} +(0pt,1cm);
\draw[->] (x.60) -- node[fill=white] {d} +(0pt,1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Claudio Fiandrino** has mentioned in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166252/tikz-block-diagram-with-multiple-arrows-not-from-centre-of-block/166254?noredirect=1#comment381945_166254), another option is to use the `calc` library, so the shifts are not absolute, but can be calculated in terms of anchors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum size=2cm] (x) {X};
\draw[->] ([yshift=-10pt]x.west) -- node[fill=white] {a} +(-1cm,0pt);
\draw[->] ([yshift=10pt]x.west) -- node[fill=white] {b} +(-1cm,0pt);
\draw[->] (x.120) -- node[fill=white] {c} +(0pt,1cm);
\draw[->] (x.60) -- node[fill=white] {d} +(0pt,1cm);
\draw[->]
  ( $ (x.north east)!0.5!(x.east) $ ) -- 
    node[fill=white] {e} 
  +(1cm,0pt);
\draw[->] 
  ( $ (x.east)!0.5!(x.south east) $ ) -- 
    node[fill=white] {f} 
    +(1cm,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above example `( $ (x.north east)!0.5!(x.east) $ )` means the point whose coordinate is halfway between `x.north east` and `x.east`.

Comment: What about the `calc` library?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I wanted to show some options without libraries, but perhaps it's worth also mentioning `calc`. Do you mean to use `calc` to calculate the shifts?

Comment: Yes, for example `\draw[->]($(x.north west)!0.5!(x.west)$)-- node[fill=white] {b} +(-1cm,0pt);` and `\draw[->] ($(x.west)!0.5!(x.south west)$) -- node[fill=white] {a} +(-1cm,0pt);`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I added some example with your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Many thanks for that quick and detailed answer!

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*\Width{\fpeval{2*\arrowLength+\boxLength}}
\newcommand*\Height{\boxLength}

\def\arrowLength{3}
\def\boxLength{3}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\Width,\Height)
 \psset{arrows = ->}
  \psframe(\arrowLength,0)(\fpeval{\arrowLength+\boxLength},\boxLength)
  \rput(\fpeval{\arrowLength+0.5*\boxLength},\fpeval{0.5*\boxLength}){X}
  \pcline(\arrowLength,\fpeval{\boxLength/3})(0,\fpeval{\boxLength/3})
  \ncput*{a}
  \pcline(\arrowLength,\fpeval{2/3*\boxLength})(0,\fpeval{2/3*\boxLength})
  \ncput*{b}
  \pcline(\fpeval{2*\arrowLength+\boxLength},\fpeval{0.5*\boxLength})%
         (\fpeval{\arrowLength+\boxLength},\fpeval{0.5*\boxLength})
  \ncput*{c}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that the drawing is 'automated' and all you have to do is choose the values of `\arrowLength` and `\boxLength`.