# drawing a picture using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I need to draw this picture using tikz. Could you please tell me how can I do that?[image]

Comment: Can you add an MWE?

Comment: First, read the rikz manual.  You can locate points on the edge of a node by naming the node and using ($(name.north west)!.1!(name.south west)$) for example with the calc tikzlibrary.

Comment: This should get you some of the way I think: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57285/multiple-arrows-between-nodes Edit: and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166252/tikz-block-diagram-with-multiple-arrows-not-from-centre-of-block

Comment: Maybe you could adapt the code provided in response to your earlier do-it-for-me at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347862/drawing-this-picture-using-tikz? Or are you going to simply keep posting pictures until somebody else has provided you with code for the lot? That is not how this site is supposed to work.

Comment: @cfr, and still no ducks requested... Nothing has been learned. `:P`

Comment: Why does your circuit have classical input but quantum output?  This circuit does not make sense.  Also the arrow is commonly used to denote the end of a circuit.

Answer (score 7):

For quantum circuits you can use the [`qcircuit`](https://ctan.org/pkg/qcircuit) package (which is based on [`xypic`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xypic)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}
\begin{document}
\[
\def\p{\parbox{2.3cm}{\centering passive \\ interferometer}}
\def\s{\mbox{squeezer}}
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=2ex {
  \lstick{1} & \multigate{5}{\p} & \gate{\s} & \multigate{1}{\p} & \rstick{\ket{\psi}} \qwa \\
  \lstick{2} & \ghost{\p}        & \gate{\s} & \ghost{\p}        & \qwa \\
  \lstick{3} & \ghost{\p}        & \qw       & \qw               & \qwa \\
  \lstick{4} & \ghost{\p}        & \qw       & \qw               & \qwa \\
  \rstick{\vdots} \\
  \lstick{k} & \ghost{\p}        & \qw       & \qw               & \qwa
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]